# How do I find the union of two arrays of models by model attribute in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array of the current_user's FB friends and another of other users that belong to a given event.

I need to find all of the current_user's FB friends that also belong to the event.

Tried this in my events_controller:

```
@friends = Array.new
@the_others = Array.new
@event.users.each do |user|
  @fb_user.friends.each do |friend|
    if friend.identifier == user.uid
      @friends << user
    else
      @the_others << user
    end
  end
end
```

Clearly this is way off...in fact it's not working...someone please set me straight :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@friends = Array.new
@the_others = Array.new
@event.users.each do |user|
   if @fb_user.friends.detect{|friend| friend.identifier == user.uid}
     @friends << user
   else
     @the_others << user
   end
end
```

Comment: Works great...when both arrays contain only a few objects. Any thoughts on how to scale this? Is it just a matter of throwing resources at it? If I have 200 users belonging to an event and a current_user with 600 FB friends...that's a lot of crunching.

Comment: I think by definition you can't optimise it that much. See: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=444725

Comment: I figured as much. Thinking now about a combination of Delayed Job and and AJAX so the page loads right away and then gets updated when the job is complete.

Answer (score 0):

```
@friends = [1,2]
@the_others = [2,3,4]
union = @friends | @the_others
 => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: This will work given that I need to join on the "identifier" attribute in the friend models and the "uid" attribute in the_other models?